# git and packed vs. loose files

Tags: windows, git

Most of the guidance that I can find says that Git prefers to improve performance by combining loose files into "packs", which by default are unlimited in size.  This does indeed improve *disk usage* (since packs allow delta compression between similar objects), but I'm not entirely convinced about *performance*.

I have a relatively large repository (800k objects).  Git's default behaviour seems to prefer packing all of these objects into a single 6GB file.  However in this state some tools have trouble dealing with the repository because they keep trying to memory-map the entire 6GB file over and over again.  This is particularly noticeable where something wants to walk through history (eg. showing the log with some extra detail, although `git log` itself doesn't seem to be affected).  I've also seen some discussion where large packs cause problems with fetch/push operations due to one end thrashing or running out of memory entirely.

As an experiment, I tried unpacking everything into individual loose files.  The size has grown (to 10GB), but everything I've tried so far has been extremely fast.

All of Git's options and auto-gc behaviour seems opposed to having large numbers of loose files, and yet as far as I can tell this is the best state for performance (just not for disk usage).  Can anyone explain this discrepancy?

Comment: I'm not quite sure this is appropriate for StackOverflow, but I will note that performance is quite tricky: some things that perform very well on System A perform terribly on System B, and vice versa.  This depends on OS, memory, disks (or flash/SSD/etc), and so on.

Comment: Huh? "Memory-map the entire 6GB file" doesn't make sense. The word "entire" there gives a very strong impression that you think this loads the whole file into memory. That's not what memory mapping does.

Comment: Good read: http://githubengineering.com/counting-objects/

Comment: I have observed thrashing on calls to `MapViewOfFile`, and that memory usage of the process increases by the size of the pack file when doing so (I had a 17GB pack file during one test).  If that's not mapping the entire file into memory, then it's close enough.